# RStudio Connect: unable to deploy in R version 4.0.0

Tags: r, rstudio, packrat

I recently updated my R version to 4.0.0 and since then I'm unable to deploy any content to RStudio Connect. I tried deploying different R Markdown projects, which worked perfectly a few weeks ago, and the result is always the same.

The Deploy Tab shows something like this:

```
Preparing to deploy document...DONE
Uploading bundle for document: 4102...DONE
Deploying bundle: 22378 for document: 4102 ...
[Connect] Building R Markdown document...
[Connect] Bundle requested R version 4.0.0; using /opt/R/3.6.2/bin/R which has version 3.6.2
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.130729666 Using user agent string: 'RStudio R (3.6.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu x86_64 linux-gnu)' 
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.740796898 linux distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (bionic) 
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.741851066 # Validating R library read / write permissions --------------------------------
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.742375910 R version: 3.6.2
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.762098813 # Validating managed packrat installation --------------------------------------
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.762572854 Vendored packrat archive: /opt/rstudio-connect/ext/R/packrat_0.5.0-25_448aafd176ec6cbde307f556c91b39e5a1c94f9d.tar.gz
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.801389677 Vendored packrat SHA: 448aafd176ec6cbde307f556c91b39e5a1c94f9d
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.803332420 Managed packrat SHA:  448aafd176ec6cbde307f556c91b39e5a1c94f9d
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.804639071 Managed packrat version: 0.5.0.25
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.805725002 Managed packrat is up-to-date.
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:51.806122325 # Validating packrat cache read / write permissions ----------------------------
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:52.187402703 Audited package hashes with local packrat installation.
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:06:52.225422249 # Installing required R packages with `packrat::restore()` ---------------------
```

Then packrat installs several cached packages and after a while it shows the following:

```
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:10:03.136084340 Warning message:
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:10:03.136181457 In packrat::restore(overwrite.dirty = TRUE, prompt = FALSE, restart = FALSE) :
[Connect] 2020/05/12 08:10:03.136208254   The most recent snapshot was generated using R version 4.0.0
```

After that, the deployment keeps loading forever with no changes and if I try to open the projects in Connect, I receive an Error 504.

How can I solve this? Do I have to get back to R version 3.6.2?

Comment: If you have Connect, don't you have support with RStudio? I would probably contact them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you will need to get your admin to install R v4.0 on the server. You don't need to upgrade R, you can have multiple versions installed. However unlike packages, which can be updated automatically by the server, the base versions of R need to be manually installed.